# Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error. -> ExecutablePath /usr/bin/lsb_release

Tags: 12.04, apport

Running Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit.
Recently I start seeing this internal error any time after I open the terminal and today after I opened a file in gedit.
Could anybody explain me what cause the error and a possible fix.

-> ExecutablePath:
 /usr/bin/lsb_release

-> Package:
 lsb-release 4.0-0ubuntu20.2

-> ProblemType: Crash

-> Title:
 lsb_release crashed with IOError in getstatusoutput():[Errno 10] No child processes
...

this is just a part of the Error report problem box, can't upload screenshot (not enough reputation)
Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is caused by a conflict with TeamViewer and has been addressed [on the official Ubuntu bugtracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lsb/+bug/1094218). A solution is provided by "gerlos (gerlosgm)" in comment #39 of said link. Also, a Ticket has been sent to Teamviewer on 2013-5-8 by MRiekerk (mattijs-riekerk) in comment #54 of same link.

In the meanwhile, the crash can be averted by removing TeamViewer with `sudo apt-get remove teamviewer`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, does it matter if the teamviewer is running or not?

Comment: No, the error is on boot or reboot.  Teamviewer just need to be installed to reproduce.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Can't uninstall the thing, but at least I know what's causing it.